# How long does it take for cows to grow up in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The title says it all, how long does it take for a cow to go from baby cow to cow. I'm using minecraft 1.7.2. Is there anyway to speed it up or slow it down? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All babies obtained by breeding take 20 minutes to grow up. There is no way to speed up this process, except for sheep, which can grow faster if they eat grass, and foals or colts (baby horses) which you can feed to speed up their growth. You can re-breed animals after 5 minutes.

**Edit/update:** As of release 1.8, baby animals' growth can slowly be accelerated using the animal's breeding item, where each use takes 10% off the remaining time to grow up.

Comment: There are a couple of exceptions: Sheep can grow faster if they eat grass and Foals (baby horses) can be fed to speed their growth.

Answer (score 1):

Cows take about 2 to 3 minecraft days. If you're lucky they  grow up in one day. You cannot change the speed in any way

[image]